# How can I write a string to format row data to save as a CSV file?

Tags: c#, string, csv, datagridview

I currently have a program which uses StreamReader to access a CSV file and store the values in a data grid, however when saving this data it is printing a new line for each column value of the data row.

The program currently prints the csv file as:

> headerText, headerText, headerText, headerText
>   Column 1, Column 2, Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4

What I need it to print is:

> headerText, headerText, headerText, headerText
>   Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4

```
string CsvFpath = "C:/StockFile/stockfiletest.csv";

try
{
    StreamWriter csvFileWriter = new StreamWriter(CsvFpath, false);
    string columnHeaderText = "";
    int countColumn = stockGridView.ColumnCount - 1;

    if (countColumn >= 0)
    {
        columnHeaderText = stockGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
    {
        columnHeaderText = columnHeaderText + ',' + stockGridView.Columns[i].HeaderText;
    }

    csvFileWriter.WriteLine(columnHeaderText);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow dataRowObject in stockGridView.Rows)
    {
        if (!dataRowObject.IsNewRow)
        {
            string dataFromGrid = "{0} += {1} += {2} += {3}";
            dataFromGrid = dataRowObject.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
            {
                dataFromGrid = dataFromGrid + ',' + dataRowObject.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                csvFileWriter.Write(dataFromGrid);
            }
            csvFileWriter.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    csvFileWriter.Dispose();

    MessageBox.Show("Saved stockfile.csv");
}
catch (Exception exceptionObject)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exceptionObject.ToString());
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with my String formation and how to achieve the required file output?

Comment: Note that it is generally bad idea to invent your own serialization code... There are plenty existing CSV libraries that will take care of quotes, commas and other fun characters coming from the values...

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Thank you for the advice, in this project I was restricted to certain conditions, I am currently studying programming cert IV so even if I couldn't use that advice on this project I will certainly take it on board in future, if I can find an easier way I'll always take it, sometimes being lazy can be a good thing, as it is with not using more code than necessary or performing functions better done with other sources.  Thanks mate I'll take your advice on board going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, the issue is that you are writing to the file *inside* the loop as you process each column, instead of *after* the loop, when you have collected all the column information for the row.

Another way you could do this is to use `string.Join` and `System.Linq` to more concisely concatenate the column values for each row.

Also note that we can wrap the `csvFileWriter` in a `using` block, so that it automatically gets closed and disposed when the block execution completes:

```
using (var csvFileWriter = new StreamWriter(CsvFpath, false))
{
    // Write all the column headers, joined with a ','
    csvFileWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(",",
        stockGridView.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Select(col => col.HeaderText)));

    // Grab all the rows that aren't new and, for each one, join the cells with a ','
    foreach (var row in stockGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where(row => !row.IsNewRow))
    {
        csvFileWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(",",
            row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(cell => cell.Value.ToString())));
    }
}
```

---

Another thing: Instead of writing your own csv parser, there are existing tools that you can use to write csv files, such as [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper), which will handle other sorts of edge cases that can cause problems, such as values that have commas in them.

Comment: That code work absolutely perfectly, it has also shown me how easy it is to clean up and streamline code, the blocks I had before were like a book compared to your snippet, so thank you very much.  It is greatly appreciated and valued knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
{
  dataFromGrid = dataFromGrid + ',' + dataRowObject.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
      csvFileWriter.Write(dataFromGrid);
}
```

You're adding to the string each time.. and not clearing it at any point. So on line 1 column one you get ",col1" col2 is ",col1,col2" .. but you're also writing them out each time..

There is a CSV writer class, but, you can do what you're doing, but, just move the write outside the loop, and then reset it. However..

```
for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
{
      if (i>1) csvFileWriter.Write(",");
      csvFileWriter.Write(dataRowObject.Cells[i].Value.ToString());
}
```

will stop you getting the extra "," at the start, and write as it goes

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out what I was doing wrong, I was in the process of putting into practice when Rufus posted his code snippet, which has not only worked perfectly it also showed me how I could reduce that over-sized code block down to something far more readable and manageable. Your help has been invaluable, thanks again.